# Building a homology/cohomology from generalized tensor invariants

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

It is known from Tensor Algebra that for a given Tensor $A$ the quantities $I_1 = tr(A)$, $I_{dim(A)} = det(A)$ are the invariants of the Tensor. More precisely, if $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $I_k$ is the k-th invariant which is simply the sum of all combinations in a k-fold product of $\lambda_i$ without mutiplying any eigenvalue by itself.

This structure remembers me on the simplicial complex $\Sigma_n:=[\sigma_1 ... \sigma_n]$. The simplicial complex contains the boundary map $\partial: \Sigma_n \rightarrow \Sigma_{n-1}$ and is defined by $\partial[\sigma_1 ... \sigma_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}[\sigma_1 ... >\sigma_i< \sigma_n]$ where $ >...< $ means the exclusion of some certain element. However, the definition of Tensor invariants doesn't contain alternating signs. But indeed, one could define a map: $\Delta:I_k \rightarrow I_{k-1}$. This map is simply the non-alternating sum of removements of eigenvalues. For ordinary complex numbers this wouldn't be an exact map. But what is when the Eigenvalues are Grassmannian numbers (Grassmannian numbers are anticommutative numbers)? Then one can construct a Long exact sequence (depending on the dimension of the tensor):

$I_k \rightarrow I_{k-1} \rightarrow I_{k-2} \rightarrow ...$.

This hold because the mappings between the invariants in the case of anticommuting objects are quite similar to the boundary map on simplices. Analogously, it can be constructed a cohomology theory with this assumptions.

Is my idea mathematically plausible? I would be happy for any comments to this idea.